# C# DataGridViewRow.Displayed bug for first row?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I have a Form where some Controls update according to the current displayed Rows (and their positions) in a DataGridView. So inside the `dataGridView1.VerticalScrollBar.ValueChanged` event I iterate through all rows and check wether they are displayed or not.

So here's the issue when scrolling back to top (by mousewheel):

- `dataGridView1.VerticalScrollBar.Value` is `0` -> OK
- `dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex` is `0` -> OK
- `dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` is `0` -> OK
- `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Displayed` is still `false` -> huh?
- `dataGridView1.GetRowDisplayRectangle(0, false)` is also `{0,0,0,0}` -> ...?

After checking https://referencesource.microsoft.com, I realized that `FirstDisplayedCell` actually uses `this.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible | DataGridViewElementStates.Frozen)`, which seems kind of incorrect, or am I wrong? 
How do I fix this, so that I get the correct displayed information / rectangle of the first row?

Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Person> persons = new List<Person>()
    {
        {new Person("mike", 20) },
        {new Person("tim", 31) },
        {new Person("steven", 15) },
        {new Person("dave", 41) },
        {new Person("tom", 35) },
        {new Person("bob", 18) },
        {new Person("peter", 22) },
        {new Person("sarah", 55) },
        {new Person("robert", 69) },
        {new Person("andre", 23) },
    };
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(this.persons, null);

        if (typeof(DataGridView).GetProperty("VerticalScrollBar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) is PropertyInfo pi &&
             pi.GetValue(this.dataGridView1, null) is ScrollBar sb)
        {
            sb.ValueChanged += this.Sb_ValueChanged;
        }
    }

    private void Sb_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int scrollValue = (sender as ScrollBar).Value;
        int index = this.dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
        int index2 = this.dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[index];
        bool displayed = row.Displayed;
        Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetRowDisplayRectangle(index, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the state of the `DataGridViewRow` does not update until after the scroll event is finished processing.  This is why the `DataGridViewRow.Displayed` property displays false when scrolling up to reveal a previously non displayed row.

You can use a bit of hack to queue a method to run right after the scroll event has finished by using [Control.BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=netframework-4.8).

Also, there is no reason to use Reflection to hack into the DataGridView's VerticalScrollBar.  Use the [DataGridView.Scroll Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.scroll?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

The following is a modification of your code to use the DataGridView.Scroll event and BeginInvoke to display the row state and display rectangle values obtained within the scroll event and immediately after the event.

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
    {
        int scrollValue = e.NewValue;
        int index = this.dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
        int index2 = this.dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[index];
        bool displayed = row.Displayed;
        Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetRowDisplayRectangle(index, false);

        Debug.WriteLine($"Scroll: index={index}, rect={rect}, state = {row.GetState(index)}");

        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Rectangle r = dataGridView1.GetRowDisplayRectangle(index, false);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Invoked: index={index}, rect={r}, state = {row.GetState(index)}");
        }), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right, Begininvoke probably will solve this ;)
Btw, the regular DataGridView.Scroll event is bugged and doesn't recognize all inputs (mouseWheel/mouseClick/ArrowKeys or if control doesn't have focus) - so the reflection approach is intended ;)